# Loading a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a view where i used bootstrap tabpanels. On the first tab(active one), i have the home message. On the second one i have a form with 3 input fields and a submit button. In the model function where i validate the data for those fields, I output form validation errors or success message, and after I reload the view.

```
        $data['table'] = $this -> model_admin -> get_users();
        $data['title'] = 'Administrator';

        $this -> load -> view('admin_view', $data);
```

What i want to do is to manage, after i click submit button to reload the view, but with the second tab being active. Like I could load instead of ..../admin_view.php, ..../admin_view.php#add.

Comment: you need to select the tab using bootstrap tab method $('#myTab li:eq(1) a').tab('show') // Select second tab (0-indexed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to select the tab using bootstrap tab method

```
$('#myTab li:eq(1) a').tab('show') // Select second tab (0-indexed)
```